# Apache returns 403 when I enable virtual hosts

Tags: php, apache, virtualhost, http-status-code-403

I just set up a Cent OS 6 VPS which runs LAMP perfectly until I enabled the virtual hosts.
It always returns 403 Forbidden error.

I updated /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf as following settings:

```
<Directory />
#    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews Includes ExecCGI
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
#    Order deny,allow
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
#    Deny from all
</Directory>

<Directory "/var/www/html">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    #AllowOverride None
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

NameVirtualHost *:80
```

I have created /etc/httpd/conf.d/vhosts.conf which is loaded by /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf.
(I replaced my real domain and username by "mydomain")

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerAdmin webmaster@mydomain

     DocumentRoot /home/mydomain/htdocs
     <Directory /home/mydomain/htdocs>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
     </Directory>
     ServerName mydomain
     ServerAlias mydomain
     ErrorLog /home/mydomain/logs/error.log
#     CustomLog /home/mydomain/logs/access.log common
</VirtualHost>
```

I changed the owner and permissions of both /var/www/html and /home/mydomain/htdocs.

```
drwxr-xr-x 3 apache apache 4096 Aug 15 14:23 html

drwxr-xr-x 2 apache apache 4096 Aug 18 10:18 htdocs
drwxr-xr-x 2 apache apache 4096 Aug 18 10:37 logs
```

But now I can't access the virtual host even the root documents (/var/www/html) by IP address. If I turn off (remove) the virtual host, then I can access the pages in the /var/www/html.

Can anyone help me out?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's `403 Forbidden` Then probably it's permission error, So make sure you apply permissions recursively. Type this in the Terminal

`sudo chmod 755 -R /home/mydomain/htdocs`

Try this in your conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    DocumentRoot "/path/to/your/site"

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Akar. Yes I changed the permissions recursively and the owner as well. But it returns 403 error.

Comment: Thanks a lot Akar. I think I solved the problem. I don't need to update the conf. What I have done is changed the permission of mydomain directory to 755 as well. It used to be 700.

Comment: I glad I helped you, Confirm and vote up the answer if it helped you

Comment: I would say changing the /home/mydomain/htdocs to 755 is not enough. The command should be sudo chmod 755 -R /home/mydomain. The permissions of user's folder need to be updated too. I voted your answers. Thanks for your reply again.

Comment: Yeah of course, You should be root user, Since you're editing the root folders.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved the problem by changing the permission of /home/mydomain/ directory to 755 which was 700.

Thanks for Akar's help. He did mention the permissions.

Comment: Glad I helped ya! Now confirm the answer and vote up.

Thanks!

Comment: @Jonathan while editing you can't add or remove content as you want and can't type -updated by Jonathan-, what you did is vandalizm. Please care about rules. Thank you.